# CSS and Bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a floating button with bootstrap, which is supposed to look good. I have done the initial style editing, but now I would like to add hover effects to it. How can this be done? 

This is the code I wrote: http://codepaste.net/oiszxo#


I would like to add on hover effects, but i do not know how to do that? 
Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but to add new effects on element when hover over that element, you can use peuseudo `:hover`,  after that it is up to your imagination

Comment: Yes, i know, but how do i add it in this specific situation? The given code does not work as intended...

Comment: put your inline style into the `style` tag, the `hover` may not have the power over the inline style

Comment: The code I wrote actually works well, i just did not see any results. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the what kind of hover effect you want.  You can add a simple XXX:hover styling, just like what you have tried. There are plenty of hover effects, google it. Try [this](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#effects)

Comment: The problem is that it does not work. I will rephrase the question:
<br>How do I add hover effects to this existing code?

Comment: use .whenMouse12:hover{box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #d0d0d0;} for a shadow hover effect.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I thought my code was wrong because i did not see any results :)

Comment: Is it possible to add animations to a button as mine? It would be great if the button would constantly become bigger and then smaller in a loop...

Comment: Use CSS transition-property to increase the size on hover and back smoothly